# How to extract blocks of lines between regex matches to separate files?

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a long text data file structured in time frames, each delimited by a keyword (FLAG here) followed by its number, in this manner :

```
FLAG
1
... [data for frame 1]
FLAG
2
... [data for frame 2]
```

The number of lines of each frames is supposed to be fixed, however because of an I/O issue, some of them are shorter. I want to extract each frame to a separate file (frame_1.log, frame_2.log, etc...).

Using `sed -n /FLAG/,{p;/^FLAG/q}`, I can print the content of the first frame, but is there a clean way to save each one to a new file?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263904/split-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/splitting-text-files-based-on-a-regular-expression

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/splitting-text-files-based-on-a-regular-expression

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).